# How to validate XML against XSD with imports when blocing access to external schema

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm trying to validate XMLs against an XSD (OpenXML DrawingML XSD to be precise). For security reasons we have blocked for access to external DTD and Schemas in the SchemaFactory by using the ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD and ACCESS_EXTERNAL_SCHEMA properties.

However, the OpenXML DML XSD contains plenty of references to other XSDs. I have tried to copy the files to be locally available, but the properties also block for file access so no luck there.

How do I validate against an external XSD with imports, when access to external schemas is blocked?

Comment: Basically, you need to use an (Apache, OASIS) catalog that redirects the URIs to local copies, and you need to set some kind of resolver to make sure the catalog is used. Details depend on which schema processor you are using: this looks like Java, so it's presumably either Xerces or Saxon.

Comment: We're using Javax SchemaFactory to generate the validator.

Comment: The Java SchemaFactory may return either the built-in Apache schema validator or the Saxon schema validator depending on what's on the classpath.